# Is dll present in process c++

Tags: dll, process

i want to check if a certain DLL is present in a certain process for exmple: is user32.dll present in explorer.exe,i used this code to get the process PID:

```
DWORD GetProcId(char* ProcName)
{
PROCESSENTRY32   pe32;
HANDLE         hSnapshot = NULL;

pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

if( Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) )
{
    do{
        if( strcmp( pe32.szExeFile, ProcName ) == 0 )
            break;
    }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
}

if( hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    CloseHandle( hSnapshot );

DWORD ProcId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
return ProcId;
}
```

What can i use to check if a dll is present in this PID?

Comment: Why are you checking whether a process has a particular DLL loaded? Let the process load its DLLs without interference.

Comment: I want to inject a DLL to a process and i don't want my injector injecting my DLL if its already there,its more of a safety  procedure than a necessary one

Comment: Why are you injecting a DLL? You're wandering into unsupported territory here.

Comment: Its part of a reverse engineering procedure

Comment: Okay, well understand that what you're doing is totally unsupported. Don't ship a product that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Module32First/Next the same way you used Process32First/Next

```
bool IsModulePresent(unsigned long procid,char* moduleName)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE,procid);
    MODULEENTRY32 pModule;
    pModule.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    Module32First(hSnapShot,&pModule);
    do {
        if( !strcmp(pModule.szModule,moduleName) )
            return true;

    }while(Module32Next(hSnapShot,&pModule));

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Module32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[Module32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to walk through all of the modules in a process snapshot.  There is a [detailed example at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).